# How to add image on push notification using brozot / Laravel-FCM

Tags: php, laravel, firebase-cloud-messaging

How to add image on push notification using  brozot / Laravel-FCM ?

I'm sending notifications correctly, but I would like to know how can I send an image with the notification?

I tried this code but not working

```
        $pushData = ['body' => $message, 'title'=>$title,'image'=>'image-url'];




    $pushJsonData = json_encode($pushData);
    if(count($tokens)>0)
    {


        $optionBuilder = new OptionsBuilder();
        $optionBuilder->setTimeToLive(60*20);

        $notificationBuilder = new PayloadNotificationBuilder($title);
        $notificationBuilder->setClickAction('NOTIFICATION');
        $notificationBuilder->setBody($message)->setSound('default');
        $notificationBuilder->setTag(strtotime("now"));


        $dataBuilder = new PayloadDataBuilder();
        $dataBuilder->addData(['a_data' => $pushJsonData]);

        $option = $optionBuilder->build();
        $notification = $notificationBuilder->build();
        $data = $dataBuilder->build();


        $downstreamResponse = FCM::sendTo($tokens, $option, $notification, $data);

        $downstreamResponse->numberSuccess();
        $downstreamResponse->numberFailure();
        $downstreamResponse->numberModification();

        //return Array - you must remove all this tokens in your database
        $downstreamResponse->tokensToDelete();

        //return Array (key : oldToken, value : new token - you must change the token in your database )
        $downstreamResponse->tokensToModify();

        //return Array - you should try to resend the message to the tokens in the array
        $downstreamResponse->tokensToRetry();

        // return Array (key:token, value:errror) - in production you should remove from your database the tokens present in this array
        $downstreamResponse->tokensWithError();
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to create a custom script that herance the vendor script and add some properties on it.

- Create a new path in app: app/Notifications/Message
- Add a new script called CustomPayloadNotification.php

Here you need to:

1. Extends **PayloadNotification** (vendor);
2. Add a new variable **$image**;
3. Override **__construct** method, changing the parameter type to **CustomPayloadNotificationBuilder**. Set all the variables like is in PayloadNotification and also set the new variable **$image**.
4. Override **toArray** method, setting all the properties like is in PayloadNotification and also set a new **property image** with **$image** value.

Something like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Notifications\Messages;

use LaravelFCM\Message\PayloadNotification;
use App\Notifications\Messages\CustomPayloadNotificationBuilder;

class CustomPayloadNotification extends PayloadNotification // Extends vendor script
{
    protected $image; // New variable

    /**
     * CustomPayloadNotificationBuilder constructor.
     *
     * @param CustomPayloadNotificationBuilder $builder
     */
    public function __construct(CustomPayloadNotificationBuilder $builder) // Change the type of parameter
    {
        $this->title = $builder->getTitle();
        $this->body = $builder->getBody();
        $this->icon = $builder->getIcon();
        $this->sound = $builder->getSound();
        $this->badge = $builder->getBadge();
        $this->tag = $builder->getTag();
        $this->color = $builder->getColor();
        $this->clickAction = $builder->getClickAction();
        $this->bodyLocationKey = $builder->getBodyLocationKey();
        $this->bodyLocationArgs = $builder->getBodyLocationArgs();
        $this->titleLocationKey = $builder->getTitleLocationKey();
        $this->titleLocationArgs = $builder->getTitleLocationArgs();
        $this->image = $builder->getImage(); // Set image
    }

    /**
     * convert CustomPayloadNotification to array
     *
     * @return array
     */
    function toArray()
    {
        $notification = [
            'title' => $this->title,
            'body' => $this->body,
            'icon' => $this->icon,
            'sound' => $this->sound,
            'badge' => $this->badge,
            'tag' => $this->tag,
            'color' => $this->color,
            'click_action' => $this->clickAction,
            'body_loc_key' => $this->bodyLocationKey,
            'body_loc_args' => $this->bodyLocationArgs,
            'title_loc_key' => $this->titleLocationKey,
            'title_loc_args' => $this->titleLocationArgs,
            'image' => $this->image, // Set property image with $image value
        ];

        // remove null values
        $notification = array_filter($notification, function($value) {
            return $value !== null;
        });

        return $notification;
    }
}
```

- Add a new script called CustomPayloadNotificationBuilder.php

Here you need to:

1. Extends **PayloadNotificationBuild** (vendor);
2. Add a new variable protected **$image**;
3. Create the **set/get** methods to $image;
4. Override **build** method, returning a new **CustomPayloadNotification** instead PayloadNotification.

Something like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Notifications\Messages;

use LaravelFCM\Message\PayloadNotificationBuilder;
use App\Notifications\Messages\CustomPayloadNotification;

class CustomPayloadNotificationBuilder extends PayloadNotificationBuilder // Extends vendor script
{
    protected $image; // New variable

    /**
     * Set image
     *
     * @param string $image
     *
     * @return CustomPayloadNotificationBuilder
     */
    public function setImage($image)
    {
        $this->image = $image;

        return $this;
    }
    /**
     * Get image.
     *
     * @return null|string
     */
    public function getImage()
    {
        return $this->image;
    }
    /**
     * Build an CustomPayloadNotification
     * 
     * @return CustomPayloadNotification
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return new CustomPayloadNotification($this); // Change the object returned
    }
}
```

- Reference **CustomPayloadNotificationBuilder** instead PayloadNotificationBuilder scripts in your code.
- Use the method setImage

Your code should be something like this:

```
    use App\Notifications\Messages\CustomPayloadNotificationBuilder; // Add the reference on the top of your code

    // No changes before here [...]

    $notificationBuilder = new CustomPayloadNotificationBuilder($title); // Replace here
    $notificationBuilder->setClickAction('NOTIFICATION');
    $notificationBuilder->setBody($message)->setSound('default');
    $notificationBuilder->setTag(strtotime("now"));
    $notificationBuilder->setImage("Image URL here"); // Add an image

    // No changes after here [...]
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to do some change in vendor for this

Step-1 : Go to the following url I am sharing here-

Laravel-FCM-master\Laravel-FCM-master\src\Message\PayloadNotification.php

Step-2 : here you have to add a instance variable as

protected $image;

Step - 3 find the public function __construct(PayloadNotificationBuilder $builder)

step -4 add $this->image = $builder->getImage(); in this function.

step -5 find the public function toArray()

step -6 add here 'image' => $this->image,

step -7 save and exit.

step -8 then follow this url in vendor again Laravel-FCM-master\Laravel-FCM-master\src\Message\PayloadNotificationBuilder.php:

step -9 add in above page

```
 /**
 * Indicates the image that can be displayed in the notification
 * Supports an url or internal image.
 *
 * @param string $image
 *
 * @return PayloadNotificationBuilder current instance of the builder
 */
public function setImage($image)
{
    $this->image = $image;

    return $this;
}
```

step - 10 then add

```
/**
 * Get image.
 *
 * @return null|string
 */
public function getImage()
{
    return $this->image;
}
```

step - 11 that's it, now you can easily able to add a new field in  your controller where your code was written asked in question.

simply modify as

```
    $notificationBuilder = new PayloadNotificationBuilder($title);
    $notificationBuilder->setClickAction('NOTIFICATION');
 $notificationBuilder->setBody($message)->setImage("https://yourdoamin.com/yourdesiredimage.jpeg")->setSound('default');
    $notificationBuilder->setTag(strtotime("now"));
```

and send you will get exact what you are looking for.

Comment: Are you suggesting that readers should edit files in their (Composer) vendor folder? If so, that is poor advice - this folder should not be committed to version control, and it should be able to be destroyed and reinstalled without impact on the correct running of a project. If a class needs to be modified then a project-level class should `extend` from it.

Comment: This is not poor. the vendor is outdated or missed to do this which is needy for some case like above and working very fine. @halfer

Comment: It is _never_ needed to edit classes in the `vendor` folder, except perhaps in the direst of legacy project circumstances, and even then it is an appalling hack. It nearly cannot be overstated what a bad practice it is. Are you advocating that the `vendor` folder should be committed to version control?

Comment: I wonder if you don't know what "flagging" means here. I have not flagged the answer, I have commented. "Flagging" means using the Flag feature to attract the attention of a Moderator or a Queue Reviewer.

Comment: In software engineering, it is essential to be able to take criticism. Here, if I see bad advice being propagated, I will comment, and I hope that the party giving the advice will be willing to cheerfully defend the advice they have given, or amend the advice based on my feedback. There is no competition here about who is the "smartest" - adults don't engage in those sorts of behaviours.

Comment: I am assuming that `PayloadNotificationBuilder` can be extended in a class that lives outside of the `vendor/` directory - do you think that would not work?